# Splitting Field of $x^4−2x^2−2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, splitting-field

> My question is to find the splitting field of $x^4-2x^2-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

By finding out the zeros, I find the root as $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}},-\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}},\sqrt{1-\sqrt{3}},-\sqrt{1-\sqrt{3}}$.

I also find out that $\sqrt{2}i=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{1-\sqrt{3}}$.

So, I concluded that splitting field would be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}},\sqrt{2}i)$. However, I don't know the way to prove that it is the exact splitting field. Is there any way to prove it without guessing? Thank you so much!

Comment: Show that all the four roots belong to the field you want to be the splitting field. One is already there, so only three to be checked.

Comment: I know how to prove $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}},-\sqrt{1+\sqrt{3}}$, however, how can I prove the other two?

Comment: Use the relation that suggested you to choose $\sqrt2i$.